# How many processes are created in this code?

Tags: c, fork

I have this question in my text book that I am not able to wrap my head around. The question is: What is the maximum number of processes running simultaneously in the program code below?

In the code below no return value checks are made to `fork()`, hence both parent and child will execute all of the code, right? Am I wrong in assuming that in the first `fork()` call the parent will just wait first and then exit? So the maximum number of processes running at once would be 2? (Just before the parent exits it did a fork).

```
int main()
{
    if ( fork() )
        wait(0);
    else
        exit(0);

    if ( fork() )
        wait(0);
    else
    {
        if ( fork() )
            wait(0);
        else
        {
            if ( fork() )
                wait(0);
            else
                exit(0);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I think the code is very poorly written and it is very unclear what actually happens in the code. I would be very thankful for a useful answer.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It will create 5 processes, itself plus 4 children created with forks, howover the first child is terminated before it creates the other 3 (in fact it waits for it to die before going on), so the number tops at 4 coexisting processes, and once it happens they all die together.

Comment: What do you mean "no return values are checked"?  What do you think `if( fork())` is checking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In the code below no return value checks are made to fork(), hence both parent and child will execute all of the code, right?

No. If success, `fork()` will return postive number in parent process, 0 in child process. Those `if (fork())` will be true in parent process.

> Am I wrong in assuming that in the first fork() call the parent will just wait first and then exit?

No. After `wait()` returns, that parent will continue in the next `if (fork())`, the child will exit.

> So the maximum number of processes running at once would be 2?

No. The right answer is 4.

Answer (score 0):

From the [fork(2) manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/2/fork):

> On success, the PID of the child process is returned in the parent,
>   and 0 is returned in the child. On failure, -1 is returned in the
>   parent, no child process is created, and errno is set appropriately.

So those conditions behave like this (assuming the fork succeeds):

```
if ( fork() )
{
  // parent, fork() returned the (nonzero) PID of the child process
}
else
  // child, fork() returned 0
}
```